# include ejs-partial into script tag (sails.js)

Tags: node.js, ejs, sails.js

function and I want to render an EJS-Partial or a Template with the returned data and finally append it to the DOM. I tried it with

```
var html = <%- partial('comment') %>"
```

but this gives me an Error and I tried it with the EJS templates like this

```
var html = new EJS({url: '/comment.ejs'}).render(comment);
```

but here I have the problem, that the code doesn't recognize the view folder nor the assets folder where I also tried to copy my partial file into.

Here is the code snippet of my ajax-function

```
<script>
function postComment(){
   if ($('#inputContent').val() != ''){
       $.post( "/comment/create/", $('#commentForm').serializeArray(), function(comment) {
           //var html = new EJS({url: '/comment.ejs'}).render(comment);
           //var html = "<%- partial('comment') %>";
           $(html).appendTo('.comments').hide().fadeIn(2000);
           $('#inputContent').val('');
        });
   }
}
</script>
```

has anyone a solution for my problem? thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that might help to get you where you want to go.

You can put a template in /assets/linker/template directory.  The linker directory is created when you create a new sails app using the --linker argument.  So, for example, let's say I have a template file called: addUser.ejs with the following code which adds a user to an existing table:

```
<tr data-id="<%- user.id %>" data-model="user">
        <% if (user.online) { %>
            <td><img src="./images/icon-online.png"></td>
        <% } else { %>
            <td> <img src="./images/icon-offline.png"></td>
        <% } %>
        <td><%= user.id %></td>
        <td><%- user.name %></td>
        <td><%- user.title %></td>
        <td><%- user.email %></td>
        <% if (user.admin) { %>
            <td> <img src="/images/admin.png"></td>
        <% } else { %>
            <td> <img src="/images/pawn.png"></td>
        <% } %> 
        <td><a href="/user/show/<%- user.id %>" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Show</a></td>
        <td><a href="/user/edit/<%- user.id %>" class="btn btn-small btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
        <td><form action="/user/destroy/<%- user.id %>" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Delete"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="_csrf" name="_csrf" value="<%- _csrf %>" />
        </form></td>
    </tr>
```

I can now use that template, in this example, in a separate javascript file contained in /assets/linker/js with the following:

```
$( 'tr:last' ).after(

  JST['assets/linker/templates/addUser.ejs']( obj )
);
```

So this take the template and uses obj which I passed in with the template to produce the desired html that gets appended in the dom.

***edit***

In addition, go into Gruntfile.js around line 80 should be the following:

```
var templateFilesToInject = [
'linker/**/*.html'
 ];
```

Change *.html to *.ejs.

Finally, add the underscore.js library to your assets/linker/js directory.

It's also important to have the linker directory structure.  I believe the Gruntfile.js are identical whether you use the --linker designation or not, so make a directory off assets called linker with sub directories of js, styles, and templates.  Move the existing files under assets/js assets/styles under your new linker directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried your solution, but the console tells me that JST is not defined

Comment: When you created your project initially, did you use the --linker argument? My guess is that grunt isn't finding the template.

Comment: ah ok, no I didn't use the --linker argument. But I see in my Gruntfile, that it only loads templates with *.html. I will change the extension and look if it works

Comment: No still undefined. Do I have to load a jst.js File? or install the npm package? I installed it but ist still won't recognize the JST

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some other things I discovered.

Comment: OK Update: It finally works! Thank you so much! I had really to create the project with linker. This way it generated the include script for JST in the layout.js.

Comment: What is `JST`? Where is it coming from?

Comment: Okay, it's from `sails.js`, that's the name they have choosen to call the templates file in the `Gruntfile.js`. But is there a way to use these templates from the server side?

Comment: @Vadorequest sails through a grunt task precompiles templates using the _.template method from underscore (or maybe now lodash). This returns a JST object that can be addressed by passing in the path of the template and then whatever arguments you want.

Comment: @Vadorequest here's a [link](https://github.com/irlnathan/sails-whatIsJst) to a repo for a client-side example.

Comment: Thanks for the example but I understood correctly how to use them from the client side, but I'm looking to do it from the server side, isn't that better? I'm confused between both so I just opened another SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813073/server-and-client-side-rendering-in-node-js

Comment: Note that the `--linker` argument is not needed in Sailsjs v0.10.x and the indicated changes to `Gruntfile.js` are now located in `tasks/pipeline.js`. Great answer as always @JohnGalt.