# Server and client side rendering in node.js

Tags: node.js, rendering, client-side, server-side

I don't understand the concept of client-side rendering. I have always used server-side rendering with PHP/Ruby, I don't see how it is possible to have client side rendering.

Who does the work? The browser?

If someone could give explanations or links that explains that, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Without sounding sarcastic, it is a distinction between client-side compilation/manipulation, server-side compilation/manipulation, or a combination of both.  While the browser is the thing that actually does the rendering.

**But compilation/manipulation of what?**

In general we're talking about HTML, CSS, javascript assets and maybe some data returned from a db that upon request gets compiled/manipulated into something that can be rendered on the browser as our application.

You can do this on the client-side using plain-old-javascript, jquery, backbone, angular, ember, etc.. You can do this on the server-side using plain-old-node or one of the frameworks like [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/).

Comment: But with node I see often the `client-side` rendering. When is it better than the server-side? I understand the notion of server and client, of course. It seems to me that the client side rendering is more complicated than the server, because we have to provide to the view the data to use while rendering. From the server side we already have the data.

Comment: One of the biggest reasons is the user experience can be much more app-like with client-side compilation instead of having to make round-trip's to the server every time you need to refresh something in the view.